# Como hago que a una imagen o foto se le baje la resolucion?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app

estoy trabajando para una empresa y diseño un app en Android Studio para tomar fotos nombrar la misma y también comprimirla en un 800x800

Este es el codigo sinceramente necesito ayuda con el tema de cambiar la resolucion y comprmir la imagen estoy usando algunas extensiones como la de

- butterknife
- dexter

---

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_camera)
void onCaptureClick(){

    Dexter.withContext(this)
            .withPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ))
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {
                    if (multiplePermissionsReport.areAllPermissionsGranted())
                    {
                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your camera");
                        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You accept must al permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                }
            }).check();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                img_preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

}

Comment: Una solucion increiblemente facil es simplemente cambiarle el tamaño a la imagen pero asumo que no quieres esto. sin embargo veo que habias puesto como etiqueta principal `"javascript"` ademas de `"java"` porfavor, recordar que javascript y java son lenguajes de programacion **totalmente diferentes** y no deben confundirse, incluso el sitio web en si hace enfasis en esto, en tu caso se trata de el lenguaje de programacion `Java` no `Javascript` uno no tiene que ver con el otro. te podria ayudar si fuera javascript, pero en `Java` la carga de imagenes es distinta...

Comment: Para que deseas cambiar la resolución de la imagen al tomar la fotografia?

Comment: Lo que quieres es reescalar la imagen?

Comment: Buenas para lo que quieres te recomiendo Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide , es lo que mas usan todos para fotos, fetchear o transformar la foto. al sacar foto te da una url se la das a glide y has un resize con glide. Neceistas un listener para obtener el bitmap.

Comment: Hola a todos, gracias por respoder y darme sugerencias. Voy a intentar lo que ustedes me dicen.